# Rendering a template with form inside from a service

Tags: symfony, twig

my DataTable service code is given below

```
public function dataTableTest(string $class, Request $request, $FormBuilder): Response
{
    $FormFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();
    
    $form = $FormFactory
        //->createBuilder()
        ->create('App\Form\NewsType', null, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
        ))
        ->add('task', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Some task',
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Create',
            ])
        //->getForm()
        ;

    $response = $this->twig->render('forms/FormFactory.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'FormsController',
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);

    return new Response($response);
}
```

*FormFactory.html.twig* code is

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

and i have an error

> SyntaxError  HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
> Unknown "form" function.

1 so how can render a template with twig function 'form' ? or its not possible?
2 When i render some template from service than
a)twig knows entity functions or properties like 'array.id'
b)twig does not know all twig functions like form(), form_start
and so on.
c) I think i need some extra twig dependency injections

Comment: It's certainly possible to render a form.  You have something else going on.  Are you using the actual Symfony Framework or is this some kind of standalone app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am using the actual Symfony Framework

Comment: Okay.  So does `bin/console debug:twig --filter=form` show the twig form function? Maybe you don't have the TwigBundle installed and enabled for some reason.